# How can I keep this table in a box?

Tags: html, css, html-table

If you run the snippet below you'll see a table that overflows on both axes.  What I would like is to put this in a box so you can see the horizontal and vertical scroll bars all the time.  This box should also scale with the page if the window's size is altered.  Essentially this would be like looking at a Microsoft Excel spreadsheet where there is a consistent border between the window's edge and the table border and you can see the scroll bars all the time.  How can I do this?

```css
.sidebar {
    position: fixed;
    display: block;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    background-color: #aaa;
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100px;
}

.main {
    margin-left:100px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="sidebar">
            <div>
                <p>Fixed Sidebar</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="main">
            <div class="row">
                <p>Some content above table</p>
            </div>
            <div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>
                                Column 1
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                Column 2
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                Column 3
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                Column 4
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                Column 5
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                Column 6
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td nowrap>
                                data 1
                            </td>
                            <td nowrap>
                                data 2
                            </td>
                            <td nowrap>
                                data 3
                            </td>
                            <td nowrap>
                                data 4
                            </td>
                            <td nowrap>
                                data 5
                            </td>
                            <td nowrap>
                                some really really really really long piece of data that's going to make my table overflow on the x-axis
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td nowrap>
                                data 1
                            </td>
                            <td nowrap>
                                data 2
                            </td>
                            <td nowrap>
                                data 3
                            </td>
                            <td nowrap>
                                data 4
                            </td>
                            <td nowrap>
                                data 5
                            </td>
                            <td nowrap>
                                data 6
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td nowrap>
                                data 1
                            </td>
                            <td nowrap>
                                data 2
                            </td>
                            <td nowrap>
                                data 3
                            </td>
                            <td nowrap>
                                data 4
                            </td>
                            <td nowrap>
                                data 5
                            </td>
                            <td nowrap>
                                data 6
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td nowrap>
                                data 1
                            </td>
                            <td nowrap>
                                data 2
                            </td>
                            <td nowrap>
                                data 3
                            </td>
                            <td nowrap>
                                data 4
                            </td>
                            <td nowrap>
                                data 5
                            </td>
                            <td nowrap>
                                data 6
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td nowrap>
                                data 1
                            </td>
                            <td nowrap>
                                data 2
                            </td>
                            <td nowrap>
                                data 3
                            </td>
                            <td nowrap>
                                data 4
                            </td>
                            <td nowrap>
                                data 5
                            </td>
                            <td nowrap>
                                data 6
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td nowrap>
                                data 1
                            </td>
                            <td nowrap>
                                data 2
                            </td>
                            <td nowrap>
                                data 3
                            </td>
                            <td nowrap>
                                data 4
                            </td>
                            <td nowrap>
                                data 5
                            </td>
                            <td nowrap>
                                data 6
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td nowrap>
                                data 1
                            </td>
                            <td nowrap>
                                data 2
                            </td>
                            <td nowrap>
                                data 3
                            </td>
                            <td nowrap>
                                data 4
                            </td>
                            <td nowrap>
                                data 5
                            </td>
                            <td nowrap>
                                data 6
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td nowrap>
                                data 1
                            </td>
                            <td nowrap>
                                data 2
                            </td>
                            <td nowrap>
                                data 3
                            </td>
                            <td nowrap>
                                data 4
                            </td>
                            <td nowrap>
                                data 5
                            </td>
                            <td nowrap>
                                data 6
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td nowrap>
                                data 1
                            </td>
                            <td nowrap>
                                data 2
                            </td>
                            <td nowrap>
                                data 3
                            </td>
                            <td nowrap>
                                data 4
                            </td>
                            <td nowrap>
                                data 5
                            </td>
                            <td nowrap>
                                data 6
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td nowrap>
                                data 1
                            </td>
                            <td nowrap>
                                data 2
                            </td>
                            <td nowrap>
                                data 3
                            </td>
                            <td nowrap>
                                data 4
                            </td>
                            <td nowrap>
                                data 5
                            </td>
                            <td nowrap>
                                data 6
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td nowrap>
                                data 1
                            </td>
                            <td nowrap>
                                data 2
                            </td>
                            <td nowrap>
                                data 3
                            </td>
                            <td nowrap>
                                data 4
                            </td>
                            <td nowrap>
                                data 5
                            </td>
                            <td nowrap>
                                data 6
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td nowrap>
                                data 1
                            </td>
                            <td nowrap>
                                data 2
                            </td>
                            <td nowrap>
                                data 3
                            </td>
                            <td nowrap>
                                data 4
                            </td>
                            <td nowrap>
                                data 5
                            </td>
                            <td nowrap>
                                data 6
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td nowrap>
                                data 1
                            </td>
                            <td nowrap>
                                data 2
                            </td>
                            <td nowrap>
                                data 3
                            </td>
                            <td nowrap>
                                data 4
                            </td>
                            <td nowrap>
                                data 5
                            </td>
                            <td nowrap>
                                data 6
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td nowrap>
                                data 1
                            </td>
                            <td nowrap>
                                data 2
                            </td>
                            <td nowrap>
                                data 3
                            </td>
                            <td nowrap>
                                data 4
                            </td>
                            <td nowrap>
                                data 5
                            </td>
                            <td nowrap>
                                data 6
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td nowrap>
                                data 1
                            </td>
                            <td nowrap>
                                data 2
                            </td>
                            <td nowrap>
                                data 3
                            </td>
                            <td nowrap>
                                data 4
                            </td>
                            <td nowrap>
                                data 5
                            </td>
                            <td nowrap>
                                data 6
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td nowrap>
                                data 1
                            </td>
                            <td nowrap>
                                data 2
                            </td>
                            <td nowrap>
                                data 3
                            </td>
                            <td nowrap>
                                data 4
                            </td>
                            <td nowrap>
                                data 5
                            </td>
                            <td nowrap>
                                data 6
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td nowrap>
                                data 1
                            </td>
                            <td nowrap>
                                data 2
                            </td>
                            <td nowrap>
                                data 3
                            </td>
                            <td nowrap>
                                data 4
                            </td>
                            <td nowrap>
                                data 5
                            </td>
                            <td nowrap>
                                data 6
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td nowrap>
                                data 1
                            </td>
                            <td nowrap>
                                data 2
                            </td>
                            <td nowrap>
                                data 3
                            </td>
                            <td nowrap>
                                data 4
                            </td>
                            <td nowrap>
                                data 5
                            </td>
                            <td nowrap>
                                data 6
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td nowrap>
                                data 1
                            </td>
                            <td nowrap>
                                data 2
                            </td>
                            <td nowrap>
                                data 3
                            </td>
                            <td nowrap>
                                data 4
                            </td>
                            <td nowrap>
                                data 5
                            </td>
                            <td nowrap>
                                data 6
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td nowrap>
                                data 1
                            </td>
                            <td nowrap>
                                data 2
                            </td>
                            <td nowrap>
                                data 3
                            </td>
                            <td nowrap>
                                data 4
                            </td>
                            <td nowrap>
                                data 5
                            </td>
                            <td nowrap>
                                data 6
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td nowrap>
                                data 1
                            </td>
                            <td nowrap>
                                data 2
                            </td>
                            <td nowrap>
                                data 3
                            </td>
                            <td nowrap>
                                data 4
                            </td>
                            <td nowrap>
                                data 5
                            </td>
                            <td nowrap>
                                data 6
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td nowrap>
                                data 1
                            </td>
                            <td nowrap>
                                data 2
                            </td>
                            <td nowrap>
                                data 3
                            </td>
                            <td nowrap>
                                data 4
                            </td>
                            <td nowrap>
                                data 5
                            </td>
                            <td nowrap>
                                data 6
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: give that table height and width of 100% in its container.

Comment: I was working on an answer (based on [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/udkwh5zL/)) but it still had some problems on the content above the table. No time to complete my answer currently, but perhaps the fiddle may help you or someone else find an answer.

Comment: It's kind of problematic that the "content above table" is dynamic in height. What would you expect to happen if that content is so large that it takes up an entire screen or more? What height should the spreadsheet get in this case? [Things would be much easier with a fixed height header that scrolls if necessary](http://jsfiddle.net/udkwh5zL/1/).

Comment: OK, so let's say I made that a fixed height header.  In that fiddle, the table overflows on top of the sidebar when you scroll to the right

Comment: Hmm, that's weird. In Chrome latest it does, in Firefox latest or IE11 it doesn't (the iframe doesn't even have a horizontal scrollbar on the document). Not sure what's going on, you'd have to investigate a fix for that particular issue. But in theory, the general approach from my fiddle should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving it as follows:

```css
.sidebar {
    position: fixed;
    display: block;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    background-color: #aaa;
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100px;
}
.main {
    margin-left:100px;
}
.table-viewport {
    position:absolute;
    top: 50px;
    bottom: 15px;
    left: 115px;
    right: 15px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="sidebar">
            <div>
                <p>Fixed Sidebar</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="main">
            <div class="row">
                <p>Some content above table</p>
            </div>
            <div class="table-viewport">
                    <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed">
                        <tr>
                            <th>Column 1</th>
                            <th>Column 2</th>
                            <th>Column 3</th>
                            <th>Column 4</th>
                            <th>Column 5</th>
                            <th>Column 6</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td nowrap>data 1</td>
                            <td nowrap>data 2</td>
                            <td nowrap>data 3</td>
                            <td nowrap>data 4</td>
                            <td nowrap>data 5</td>
                            <td nowrap>some really really really really long piece of data that's going to make my table overflow on the x-axis</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td nowrap>data 1</td>
                            <td nowrap>data 2</td>
                            <td nowrap>data 3</td>
                            <td nowrap>data 4</td>
                            <td nowrap>data 5</td>
                            <td nowrap>data 6</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td nowrap>data 1</td>
                            <td nowrap>data 2</td>
                            <td nowrap>data 3</td>
                            <td nowrap>data 4</td>
                            <td nowrap>data 5</td>
                            <td nowrap>data 6</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td nowrap>data 1</td>
                            <td nowrap>data 2</td>
                            <td nowrap>data 3</td>
                            <td nowrap>data 4</td>
                            <td nowrap>data 5</td>
                            <td nowrap>data 6</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td nowrap>data 1</td>
                            <td nowrap>data 2</td>
                            <td nowrap>data 3</td>
                            <td nowrap>data 4</td>
                            <td nowrap>data 5</td>
                            <td nowrap>data 6</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td nowrap>data 1</td>
                            <td nowrap>data 2</td>
                            <td nowrap>data 3</td>
                            <td nowrap>data 4</td>
                            <td nowrap>data 5</td>
                            <td nowrap>data 6</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td nowrap>data 1</td>
                            <td nowrap>data 2</td>
                            <td nowrap>data 3</td>
                            <td nowrap>data 4</td>
                            <td nowrap>data 5</td>
                            <td nowrap>data 6</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td nowrap>data 1</td>
                            <td nowrap>data 2</td>
                            <td nowrap>data 3</td>
                            <td nowrap>data 4</td>
                            <td nowrap>data 5</td>
                            <td nowrap>data 6</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td nowrap>data 1</td>
                            <td nowrap>data 2</td>
                            <td nowrap>data 3</td>
                            <td nowrap>data 4</td>
                            <td nowrap>data 5</td>
                            <td nowrap>data 6</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td nowrap>data 1</td>
                            <td nowrap>data 2</td>
                            <td nowrap>data 3</td>
                            <td nowrap>data 4</td>
                            <td nowrap>data 5</td>
                            <td nowrap>data 6</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td nowrap>data 1</td>
                            <td nowrap>data 2</td>
                            <td nowrap>data 3</td>
                            <td nowrap>data 4</td>
                            <td nowrap>data 5</td>
                            <td nowrap>data 6</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td nowrap>data 1</td>
                            <td nowrap>data 2</td>
                            <td nowrap>data 3</td>
                            <td nowrap>data 4</td>
                            <td nowrap>data 5</td>
                            <td nowrap>data 6</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td nowrap>data 1</td>
                            <td nowrap>data 2</td>
                            <td nowrap>data 3</td>
                            <td nowrap>data 4</td>
                            <td nowrap>data 5</td>
                            <td nowrap>data 6</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td nowrap>data 1</td>
                            <td nowrap>data 2</td>
                            <td nowrap>data 3</td>
                            <td nowrap>data 4</td>
                            <td nowrap>data 5</td>
                            <td nowrap>data 6</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td nowrap>data 1</td>
                            <td nowrap>data 2</td>
                            <td nowrap>data 3</td>
                            <td nowrap>data 4</td>
                            <td nowrap>data 5</td>
                            <td nowrap>data 6</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td nowrap>data 1</td>
                            <td nowrap>data 2</td>
                            <td nowrap>data 3</td>
                            <td nowrap>data 4</td>
                            <td nowrap>data 5</td>
                            <td nowrap>data 6</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td nowrap>data 1</td>
                            <td nowrap>data 2</td>
                            <td nowrap>data 3</td>
                            <td nowrap>data 4</td>
                            <td nowrap>data 5</td>
                            <td nowrap>data 6</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td nowrap>data 1</td>
                            <td nowrap>data 2</td>
                            <td nowrap>data 3</td>
                            <td nowrap>data 4</td>
                            <td nowrap>data 5</td>
                            <td nowrap>data 6</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td nowrap>data 1</td>
                            <td nowrap>data 2</td>
                            <td nowrap>data 3</td>
                            <td nowrap>data 4</td>
                            <td nowrap>data 5</td>
                            <td nowrap>data 6</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td nowrap>data 1</td>
                            <td nowrap>data 2</td>
                            <td nowrap>data 3</td>
                            <td nowrap>data 4</td>
                            <td nowrap>data 5</td>
                            <td nowrap>data 6</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td nowrap>data 1</td>
                            <td nowrap>data 2</td>
                            <td nowrap>data 3</td>
                            <td nowrap>data 4</td>
                            <td nowrap>data 5</td>
                            <td nowrap>data 6</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td nowrap>data 1</td>
                            <td nowrap>data 2</td>
                            <td nowrap>data 3</td>
                            <td nowrap>data 4</td>
                            <td nowrap>data 5</td>
                            <td nowrap>data 6</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

is this what you want?

Add such style for your `table-responsive` class

```
.table-responsive {
overflow-x: scroll;
overflow-y: scroll;
width:100%;
height:100%;}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/puorqt13/

Comment: Not quite, if you make the page smaller (y-axis) the table still doesn't show the horizontal scroll bar because it's off screen